# Como mudar posição de uma table no vuejs

Tags: html5

Atualmente se encontra assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na verdade era para ficar assim;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tendo dificuldade, alguém pode me ajudar, por favor?

Esse é o código fonte.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Desenvolvido por Wladimir Alves Bandeira</title>





<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" >
</head>
<div id="app">



<div class="table">
    <div >

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Tipo de moeda</th>
                <th scope="col">Valor</th>
                <th scope="col">Referencia</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr v-if="bancodedados" v-for="(val, key) in bancodedados.valores" :key="key">
                <td> {{  val.nome }}  </td> 
                <td> {{  val.valor }}</td>
                <td>{{  val.fonte }}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>


    </div>
</div>

</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/1.3.6/vue-resource.js"></script>


<script >

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    bancodedados: [],
  },
  methods: {

  },
  created: function() {
    var self = this;
    self.$http.get('http://api.promasters.net.br/cotacao/v1/valores').then(function(response) {
      self.bancodedados = response.body;
    });
  },

});



</script>


<style>



</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Está do outro jeito por está herdando todas as classes da tabela do Bootstrap 4. Para resolver isso vc vai ter que encapsular sua tabela dentro de um container e fazer um override com as classes do jeito que vc deseja. Se quiser eu posso fazer um modelo simples pra vc.

Comment: mostre para mim um modelo por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No caso, vou realizar a resposta mediante ao que você disse:

> Na verdade era para ficar assim;

Estou dizendo isto pois a maneira como as informações estão inseridas na tabela da maneira que está para a maneira que você quer, estão distintas. Se você deseja trazer no cabeçalho apenas as moedas, basta fazer o `v-for` no `th` e outro no `td`.

Depois, deve alterar as classes, segue exemplo abaixo que ficou semelhante ao resultado esperado ao meu ver:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',  
  data() {
    return {
      bancodedados: [
        {
          nome: 'Dóla',
          valor: 32.889,
          fonte: 'azul'
        },
        {
          nome: 'Euro',
          valor: 40.605,
          fonte: 'azul'
        },
        {
          nome: 'Peso Argentino',
          valor: 0.1629,
          fonte: 'azul'
        },
        {
          nome: 'Libra Esterlina',
          valor: 4.615,
          fonte: 'azul'
        },
        {
          nome: 'Bitcoin',
          valor: 28050,
          fonte: 'azul'
        }
      ]            
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.table th, .table td {
  border: 3px solid black !important;
  text-align: center;
}

.table th {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="app">
    <table class="table table-sm">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" v-if="bancodedados" v-for="(val, key) in bancodedados" :key="key">{{ val.nome }}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td v-if="bancodedados" v-for="(val, key) in bancodedados" :key="key"> 
            {{  val.valor }}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```